# How can I cheaply transport lots of cargo overseas?

Tags: transportation, luggage

I want to move a small library somewhere overseas (let's suppose I'm in New Jersey and am going to Melbourne), and I have over a thousand books that I want to bring with me.

Time to transport is not an issue.

I'm pretty sure that checking it as luggage on a commercial flight is out of the question. What is the cheapest way to transport that many books?

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly on-topic. I started a [meta discussion](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/978/are-questions-about-sending-stuff-abroad-on-topic) on this to clarify, but I think this type of question should be on-topic, although not in your particular circumstances since you won't be accompanying your goods and won't be using them abroad for the purposes of travelling.

Comment: Close voters: please weigh in on the meta discussion or in chat, or at least comment.

Comment: i voted to close, because for me the question is only about shipping and not about travelling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to transport a substantial amount of heavy stuff cheaply and time is not important, the obvious solution is transport by sea. There are three options that are worth investigating - which one is best/cheapest (or available at all) will depend completely on your specific origin and destination.

- **The postal service** may offer sea mail, and books may even get a discount. For example, when I moved from Japan back to Germany, I had about 50kg of books. The Japanese postal service had a special "book bag" rate (you actually got a large canvas bag, and it was restricted to books, with a maximum weight of 30kg).
- **Freight companies** often take private customers - especially those that compete with the postal service anyway, like DHL and UPS. Smaller ones may be quite cheap (subject to negotiation) but not do door-to-door delivery (i.e. they'll expect you to bring and take the cargo to/from their local office) and take longer while they wait for enough cargo to accumulate to fill a container.
- **International moving companies** obviously do this kind of thing and are probably your safest bet - just not necessarily the cheapest option. They'll also help you with things like customs.

Customs is something you'll almost certainly have to deal with for this amount of cargo - either by paying it, or by providing documents that prove it's not a commercial shipment.

As for the delivery time to expect - US East coast to Australia would be a minimum of two weeks, but could easily be a month or more if your shipment has to wait for a container to fill up.